# Generalised Volatility

Tags: statistics, finance, variance

I'm reading a financial mathematics paper and was wondering why the volatility of a price series might be given as a natural logarithm of time:

$$\sigma_T = \sigma \sqrt{\ln T}.$$

I would have thought, that the standard deviation would be given by:

$$
\sigma_T = \sigma \sqrt{T}.
$$

Can anyone explain the logic behind the first equation? I don't understand why $\ln$ needs to be used. Thanks

Comment: The context ? which asset class?

Comment: BTW, the variance is $\sigma^2T$ not  $\sigma^2\sqrt{T}$

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Referring to stock prices.

Comment: It usually *is* $\sigma_T = \sigma \sqrt T$, at least under the standard assumption that the stock is driven by a [Wiener process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Basic_properties). What model are they using to describe the stock behavior?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen $\sigma\sqrt{log(T)}$ as a stock variance ,  it is very awkward as if the maturity of the stock is smaller than 1 year, the variance does not exist !

Usually when it comes to model a stock $S_t$ , a basic model would be to assume that $log(S_t)$ is a normal process.

Indeed, it guarantees the positivity of the stock price, also the variance of the stock is proportional to its value , and it is a feature that can be observed in the market, stock with high values will tend to move more than a penny stock. 
Obviously , it can be proved easily that a lognormal process has a lot of drawbacks, the constant $\sigma$ has never been seen (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatility_smile), and historically , the returns are not normal ! However, it is the simplest well-defined distribution that we know.

Comment: Great, I didn't think there was such thing. The constant $\sigma$ is a big assumption in a lot of financial mathematics, but very necessary. Thanks for the answer!